# Deshacer el último commit en Git sin perder mis cambios locales

Tags: git, github, git-commit

quiero quitar el ultimo commit de una branch sin afectar los cambios que he realizado despues de hacer push en mi local.

He leido que se puede hacer con `git reset [--mixed] HEAD~1` pero tengo duda si al realizarlo se quedan los cambios que hice en mi local

Comment: Si se quedan `git reset HEAD~1`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `git reset --soft <id commit>` y asi conservaras tus cambios

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero me surge otra duda, de donde tomo el id del commit?

Comment: @AbrilTapia con `git log` saldra algo asi `commit b1117c09ad3d1d2feb397c3114f4c8eafcf37737
Author: qwerty <email@mail.es>
Date:   Thu Jun 6 14:26:32 2019 -0500`

Comment: Gracias, lo realice, pero no me efectuó ningún cambio "No se elimino el commit"

Comment: @AbrilTapia Muestrame por favor todo el comando completo que introduciste

Comment: $ git reset --soft a3ece7a2935432984b143e364fa53dfd0024fba2

Comment: @AbrilTapia en lugar de soft prueba con mixed